# Setup dependency of `systemd.netdev` for networking

Tags: networking, boot, vpn, systemd

I have a wireguard VPN configured for some devices using `systemd.netdev` and `systemd.network` configuration.

I suspect that even when the `wg0` device and the routes are set; they are being setup before the underlying ethernet connection is ready. And thus it is not fully automatic and I have to run the command `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`, so that the link starts to work.

Can a `systemd.netdev` depend on another `systemd.network` unit?

Is there any mechanism to delay interface setup to a time where this should be ready?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was systemd-networkd was disabled by default. I had to activate it in order for the configuration to work.

No dependency needed.